# Vectorize Numerical Integration C++ - Error Code 1200

Tags: c++, vectorization

I'm writing a numerical integration code but I'm failing to vectorize it as I keep receiving [error code 1200](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/vectorizer-and-parallelizer-messages?view=vs-2017#BKMK_ReasonCode120x).

Basically my routine is the following. The object Fxy represents a 2D function. My understanding is that the function `f` call will cause issues when it can't be inlined. However, adding keyword `inline` didn't help.

```
class Fxy
{
public:
    inline double operator()(double, double) const;
}

double integrate(Fxy f, std::vector<double> x, std::vector<double> w){
    double ans = 0.0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i){
        for (size_t j = 0; j < x.size(); ++j){
            ans += f(x[i], x[j]) * w[i] * w[j];
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: It would help to quote the full error message. I have no idea what error code 1200 means, but I might see the problem if I knew the text of the error message.

Comment: (1) What is the description of the error? 1200 means nothing to me. (2) Are you sure that `w` has size >= that of `x`? I would verify this precondition; this could be an out-of-bounds memory access. (3) The `const` qualifiers on the arguments to `Fxy::operator()` are pointless; the numbers are passed by value and the caller doesn't need to know whether the method is going to mutate its own copies. (4) What is the implementation of `Fxy::operator()`? Maybe that is where the problem is. (5) You are missing a semicolon at the end of the `ans +=` line.

Comment: (6) `inline` doesn't actually force calls to be inlined, it only suppresses the one-definition rule. The call very well may not be inlined.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I addressed most of them. The code runs perfectly just not vectorized. The implementation of `Fxy::operator()` is just a bunch of arithmetic operations.

Comment: @volJunkie The most likely reason is that the implementation of `Fxy::operator()` is not available to the compiler yet, and so cannot be inlined. Try defining the body of this operator before `integrate()` is defined.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] (with all includes and all semicolons to make the code compile). Is the implementation of `Fxy::operator()` in the same compilation unit?

Comment: You are introducing dependencies between the different iterations through `ans` variable. It stops compiler from vectorizing the loops.

Comment: This is an MSVC error. It seems to me that GCC is just smarter than MSVC when it comes to autovectorization. The same code is successfully vectorized with GCC. In my tests, `__forceinline` does not help. I even tried using `#pragma omp simd` and adding the compile flag `/openmp:experimental`, but that also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to solve this is to use `__forceinline`.

```
class Fxy
{
public:
    __forceinline double operator()(double, double) const;
}

double integrate(Fxy f, std::vector<double> x, std::vector<double> w){
    double ans = 0.0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i){
        for (size_t j = 0; j < x.size(); ++j){
            ans += f(x[i], x[j]) * w[i] * w[j];
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```